# What prevents the Ionic Security javascript SDK from being loaded by websites of malicious actors?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, ionicsecurity

The [Ionic JS SDK documentation](https://api.ionic.com/jssdk/latest/Docs/tutorial-architecture.html) mentions that [the `postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is used to communicate with an iframe running core SDK code.  Device profiles are kept in `localStorage` scoped to the origin of the iframe.

What prevents the SDK JS code (and subsequent iframe) from being loaded on a malicious site and used to access the profiles a user has created to encrypt/decrypt data?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new device profile, applications should call the [`enrollUser`](https://api.ionic.com/jssdk/latest/Docs/ISAgent.html#enrollUser) function; see: https://api.ionic.com/jssdk/latest/Docs/tutorial-device_enrollment.html

From the docs

> Upon successful authentication within the 10-minute timeout window, an enrollment profile is stored encrypted in localStorage under the appId, userId, and the origin of the calling application.

So the profile is stored encrypted. The profiles are also stored nested and namespaced by origin, appid, and userId, like this (see the `queryProfiles` function in [`ProfileManager.js`](https://api.ionic.com/jssdk/latest/Docs/common_ProfileManager.js.html)):

> profiles[origin][appId][userId]

Note that the `origin` information is pulled from the `postMessage` event object received by the sdk core code running inside the iframe.

The [`loadUser` function](https://api.ionic.com/jssdk/latest/Docs/ISAgent.html#loadUser) accepts the same params as `enrollUser` and performs the reverse operation, loading a profile from localStorage and decrypting it.

So in summary

> What prevents the SDK JS code (and subsequent iframe) from being loaded on a malicious site and used to access the profiles a user has created to encrypt/decrypt data?

An application must have access to the same `appId`, `userId`, and `userAuth` values *and* be running on the same `origin` to gain access to a profile created by another application.

In practice

- `appId` is hardcoded for a give application (i.e. in the js/html)
- `userId` and `userAuth` are stored on the application user's session object. These values can either be fetched via an ajax request to the application's origin server or written into the application html. This is similar to [normal handling practices for CSRF tokens](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md).